# Cordova on Android - Unable to Load JS or CSS

Tags: android, cordova

My Cordova project runs fine in the Ripple emulator, but when I try and run in in the Android Emulator, none of the files referenced in index.html or otherwise will load.  Instead they all return the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND".

All the files are referenced via relative path.  This includes files referenced in index.html as well as files loaded via system.js.

For instance in index.html

```
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And in system.js:

```
var map = {
    'app': 'scripts/app',
    '@angular': 'scripts/lib/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'scripts/lib/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs': 'scripts/lib/rxjs'
};
```

I believe this is due to setting the base path:

```
<base href="/">
```

I can load the dependencies by specifying an absolute path that works in Android.

For instance in index.html:

```
<link href="file:///android_asset/www/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js"></script>
```

And in system.js:

```
var map = {'app': 'file:///android_asset/www/scripts/app',
    '@angular': 'file:///android_asset/www/scripts/lib/@angular',
    'rxjs': ''file:///android_asset/www/scripts/lib/rxjs'
};
```

There has got to be a better way than this as it's not portable.  In addition there are android-specific build files that use relative paths that can't be changed. Any suggestions are appreciated.